# How to check from which optgroup an option is picked from <select> html feild

Tags: java, html, struts2

i am using  struts tag with . there are two opt groups with same keys but different values. when i submit my form, keys go to server to save. now on server side i want to check with which optgroup it was associated how can i do it ?
following is html code

```
<optgroup label="Group1">
<option value="1">opt1</option>
<option value="3">opt2</option>
<option value="4">opt3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group2">
<option value="1">opt4</option>
<option value="3">opt5</option>
<option value="4">opt6</option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different values, such as:

```
<option value="grp1_1">opt1</option>
```

...

```
<option value="grp2_1">opt1</option>
```

Then parse out the value on the server after the for is submitted.

Comment: these key value pairs are coming from db. there will be lot of effort required to remap all values in code.

Comment: That's your only choice. Optgroups are for display-only. They have no associated data element that's sent back to the server.

Comment: @RahulTathod Why not provide your own answer, instead of editing this one?